# LoaderCallbacks and screen orientation

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

I have an `Activity` implement `LoaderCallbacks` and start an `AsyncTaskLoader` from that `Activity`. 
When (due to a screen orientation change) the `Activity` is being destroyed while the `AsycTaskLoader` is still loading, the `Activity` seems to 'lose the connection' to the `Loader` and `onLoadFinished` isn't called. 
How can I reattach my `Activity` to the `Loader` so the callback methods are called? 
I know I can get 'a hold' of the loader with

```
getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(loaderID)
```

but I don't know any further.

Comment: your application crashing when you the change the screen orientation while fetching result in async task?

Comment: No it isn't, the Loader finishes it's work but never 'publishes' it to the Activity.

Comment: So your project works fine when you don't change the screen orientation right?

Comment: Yes. I noticed that the AsyncTaskLoaders onReset() is being called before the Loader finishes even without orientation change, but I guess that's standard behaviour?
Anyway, it works fine when there's no orientation change.